# Retrieve particular value from multiple tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2017

I have 14 tables of different kinds of employees. I have a C# application which is wired to my SQL Server database and when I type a last name  in a textbox it brings back a record with that last name and displays it in a listbox.

However I have managed to do this with only one table. So if I type “Jones” it will bring back and display Jones from one table.

I would like to bring back all the Jones’ from all 14 tables. In other words, when I type a last name, I need the application to show me all records of that last name from all 14 tables.

What would be a reasonable approach to this? It would be a lot easier if I had one table with all employees but I need the seperation. Basically when I click the search button I need the application to go fetch from any of the 14 tables with the given name.

What would be a suitable approach to this?

Comment: why do you need the separation? You could create a view that unions the 14 tables but having one table could be much better for performance.

Comment: Well I wanted the staff divided into categories because I dont know how Im going to expand the app later on. I liked the idea of Sales, Technical Dept, Managers etc etc instead of having all categories and all staff in one category. I get what you’re saying though I do need to create common ground for all these guys.

Comment: @NikosKap why not just assign category for each user instead of creating table for each category?

Comment: That could be a possibility.

Comment: @Neir0 This, in fact is a very useful suggestion. I’m thinking seriously about refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following stored procedure in your database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAll_SP
(
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
)  
AS
    BEGIN
        (SELECT 1, first_name, last_name FROM UsersTable1 WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
        UNION
        (SELECT 2, first_name, last_name FROM UsersTable2 WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
        UNION
        (SELECT 3, first_name, last_name FROM UsersTable3 WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
        -- ....
    END

GO
```

or the following one instead of you don't need to have any kind of control over your users location:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAll_SP
(
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
)  
AS
    BEGIN
        (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM UsersTable1 WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM UsersTable2 WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM UsersTable3 WHERE first_name = @FirstName)
        -- ....
    END

GO
```

Then, in your code:

```
String firstName = "Jones";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAll_SP", m_Connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName;

    m_Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I’ll try this and check back. I’ll have to make a few changes though in my C# because I’m using Lists and Dapper so should be interesting. I’ll check back thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat your Code 14 Times to collect values from all this tables or you submit a SQL Query for all 14 Tables at once with unions or 14 queries in one Statement - depending on your Data Access Technology...

Comment: Could I add a stored procedure with 14 lookups and then call the stored procedure in the app? Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I’ll try that out and check back.

Comment: Thats basically what I need but I need to pull from 14 tables. Don’t know if that helps you guys at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to get results from all 14 tables you can use `UNION ALL` Operator, so your SQL would look something like:

```
(SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table1 WHERE first_name='John')
 UNION ALL
(SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table2 WHERE first_name='John')
...
(SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table14 WHERE first_name='John')
```

You need to have equal amount of fields in every select. However better approach would be if you save all names (and any other shared data) in one table, and connect with Key with all those 14 tables that have different dataset. That way you can prevent such a long queries like this one above (and probably slow queries) and query would look more like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, user_type, user_id  WHERE first_name='John'
```

And then you can retreive fields from corresponding table as field `user_type` gives you info in which out of 14 tables to search for other data and user_id gives you data of that user, so second query would look something like this:

```
SELECT job_position, worksheet, other_data FROM tableN WHERE user_id=...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set @SearchStr and every column in every table will be searched.

```
drop table #results
go

declare @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
set @SearchStr = 'Donna%' -- use wildcards

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'text')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

    print cast(@TableName as nvarchar(200)) + ' ' + @ColumnName

    IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                --'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                --FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                --' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2

                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', ' + @ColumnName + ' 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
```